# Javascript code inside tag runs after show animation is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div container with javascript code inside, I cant move the code outside so what can i do to prevent runing this fot the second time 
Heres the link to the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/f5caT/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the alert should only be shown on page load then you can simply remove the script block before animating the div

http://jsfiddle.net/f5caT/8/

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(e){
     $('#hidden')
         .find("script").remove().end()
         .show('slide',1000);
    });

});​
```